# Bitcoin sendmany command fails? lose some addresses

Tags: python, bitcoin

Occur where a command is used sendmany to 85 destinations ( with funds from an account with 85 pre-loaded with funds addresses --- > out in 85 to 85 ).

Before running the command destination addresses are loaded into a dictionary in python checking that none of the amounts is less than the minimum , the addresses are all valid , the accumulated funds are sufficient in all amounts correspond to balances in the source account , etc.

The program executes the command without returning any exceptions , no errors in the shipment , but when you look at the transaction is confirmed in his field " details" that has the 85 category "send" and only 58 category "receive " and therefore you lose the difference between the BTC in and out , probably going in the form of commissions for the network, but that is not correct since missed 27 address that did not receive the funds.

I'm using python 2.7 and bitcoinrpc library.

No one can understand what the problem is , anyone can help .
Thank you.

Comment: Are you using blockchains bitcoin rpc library?

Comment: To be more specific, are you using this: https://blockchain.info/api/json_rpc_api or the actual daemon.